# How to structure C# class library?

Tags: c#, .net, api, class-library

good day! I need your help.. how do you write and structure your code in a class library such that when it is built as dll other programmers can use that dll as their library more like the base class library. except that i dont know how to structure them are there any rules in writing a good library? best practices maybe?
so that my library will be elegant and much like the base class libraries in .net

please help.. thanks!

Comment: Perhaps look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) and copy that format.

Comment: This is a bit of an ambiguous question, but one piece of advice I would give you is learn how to create a NuGet package with your library in it. It'll make managing the DLLs across your team far, far easier.

Comment: I don't see the point in writing a good library , what is essentially needed is writing a good code.Anyway the users will not know about the library other than the publicly defined types , so why do you care about this ? Yeah if you are deviated from the library name then it would be confusing for the users . So if you name the library well and the types inside it offers what is mentioned in the library name then your need is satisfied and also the users will be happy. For an eg: if you name the library as Sqlclient.dll and if you define type for web service its a problem.

Answer (score 14):

This should help: [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Actually a good reading for all .net developers.

Answer (score 1):

Use static code analysis (FxCop). It'll enforce all of Microsoft's guidelines/best practices for library development.

Comment: But it won't suggest 'elegance'.